# Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA create new project failed with error message 'invalid type code: 00'

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, jrockit

I've just downloaded Android Studio and updated to 0.3.6 before trying to create a new project. I was able to see the creation screen, enter basic info for the new project, create icon etc, however when project creation process was finishing it would throw the error below:
[image]

Restarting Android Studio doesn't fix the problem. And from the launch screen shown above, I can't check out the IDE log for more details as the instruction says either.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and what's the fix?

I am on a Windows 7 64-bit machine and have Oracle JRockit 1.6.0 as the JVM if it helps.

---

**Edit:**

Here's the essence from the log file @C:\Users\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log\idea.log

> 2013-11-24 11:58:58,393 [  33993]   INFO -
>   .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
>   org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build
>   action using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip'.    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$000(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:441)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:495)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:657)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)    at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException:
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00 Caused by:
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2486)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(ObjectInputStream.java:2521)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2593)
>     at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2798)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:948)    at
>   java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1213)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1969)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:150)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:33)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:25)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

The thing is that I can download 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip' without issues, so I don't know why Android Studio would fail to obtain it. Is it possible for me to manually put the file somewhere so the action would not fail?

Comment: Have you tried to unistall and reinstall the program?

Comment: The logfile would go a long way toward helping troubleshoot the problem. You can consult http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181 to find it.

Comment: @user2675569 Yes indeed I have, didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Gradle (or Android Studio) doesn't like for JRocket JVM to be set as the default Java runime.

Set JAVA_HOME to use JDK completely fixed the problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the files that Gradle has downloaded has become corrupted. I'd try removing all Gradle cache directories; there should be a .gradle directory in your user home directory (I'm not 100% sure where it will go on Windows; you may need to hunt around for all .gradle directories to find it) as well as the .gradle directory in your project's root. Though if you're just trying to create a new project each time, then it will create a new project root directory each time, so the project-root-specific one isn't going to be causing your problems.

If this doesn't help you (I'm a little skeptical that it will), then you'll need to see what else is going on in your system that would be corrupting these files. If you have antivirus or other sorts of systemwide utilities that aren't part of Microsoft's base operating system, have a look at temporarily disabling those to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: I have tried the deleting .gradle dir method, didn't work as you suspected. Will try the anti-virus method when I get home from the office.

Comment: The issue isn't with antivirus or other applications, but with the JVM used (not sure why), but you set me on the right path, thanks!